# What is the reasonable choice of memory for DZ77GA-70K + Intel 3770K nowadays?

Tags: memory

What is the reasonable choice of memory for DZ77GA-70K + Intel 3770K nowadays?
this MB supports for DDR3 1066 MHz to +2400 MHz.

- Is it worth to buy memory faster 1600MHz?
- Should it support XMP?
- should it be dual channel?
- should it be the same model (I have 16Gb and need additional 16Gb but ready to buy 32 if answer is Yes)?

"Should" here means - is it worth? Because three years ago I encountered  [posts](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/352083-28-3770k-speeds-compatibility-help) that say Intel processors do not leverage increase of frequency according to price differences. Is it true for nowadays?

Comment: Memory these days is dual channel, you don't have a choice. [see the Intel page for tested memory for that board](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dz77ga-70K/sb/CS-033219.htm) Yes 1600 mhz will be faster than 1300.

Comment: "XMP version 1.3 performance profile support for memory speeds above 1600 MHz" from the link i posted.

Comment: "Worth" can only be determined by you.

Comment: Not sure how this question was interpreted as merely a shopping recommendation? Surely the dot points imply it is looking for analysis on how to choose suitable RAM? "Reasonable choice" doesn't necessarily mean "tell me an exact model".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a number of factors, but in general: no, RAM faster than 1600MHz doesn't give you much of a boost. If the price was the same and you were interested in RAM overclocking, sure grab a 2400MHz kit, but otherwise 1600MHz will likely be just as good.

Some of the factors are:

- What tasks are you running (rendering? gaming? office stuff?);
- If gaming, is the game CPU-bound or GPU-bound (the former may benefit from faster RAM, but even then most don't);
- Are you using onboard graphics or a dedicated GPU? Intel onboard doesn't seem to scale like AMD APUs with RAM speeds, but may make a difference.

A couple of articles using the 3770K that show 1600 more or less the same as 2400 except in some specialised cases:

- http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ivy-bridge-benchmark-core-i7-3770k,3181-10.html
- http://www.anandtech.com/show/6372/memory-performance-16gb-ddr31333-to-ddr32400-on-ivy-bridge-igp-with-gskill/12

On expansion: Try and run in dual-channel. If using existing RAM, try and match the specs as closely as possible with any new RAM you buy. Keep the paired sticks running in corresponding dual-channel slots. While DDR3 incompatibility seems *relatively* rare, there is no guarantee separately purchased sticks will work together -- you'd need a manufacturer-tested 4x8GB kit to get that guarantee.

When looking for RAM compatibility, Intel's list is pretty limited. RAM suppliers often have their own lists. (As an example, the listing for [G-Skill Ares](http://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-1600c9d-8gao) has your motherboard in the QVL).

Comment: This is as good an answer as you can get.